# python : [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen, file-not-found

I am facing a rather strange issue. I'm trying to run a .js script inside a python script. In my .js script I convert .pdf to json and then call this .js script inside .py script which converts this json to .xlsx.

But using Popen to execute the .js script the error appears : "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified".
I've rechecked the error location almost 10 times now. I've checked the cwd too its correct.
Everything's is in place except this error. Please help me. :(

```
import pandas as pd
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
bankType = "parsePmc"
parser_path = os.path.join(cwd, "parse_pmc_bank_pdf.js")
input_file_path = os.path.join(cwd, "bs.pdf")
output_file_path = os.path.join(cwd, "bs_excel.xlsx")
print(parser_path)
print(input_file_path)
print(output_file_path)
#parser_path = parser_path.replace("\\","\\\\") #(Even this doesn't work.)
print(parser_path)
args = ["node", parser_path, input_file_path, output_file_path] #I've even checked it using with str() for the paths.
print(os.getcwd())
p = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print(stdout)
if bool(stderr):
    print(stderr)
else:
    df = pd.read_json(output_file_path)
    if df.empty:
        print("EMPTY XLSX")
    else:
        df.to_excel(output_file_path, sheet_name='Raw')

[Error:] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-e3dffdd7e5db> in <module>()
      1 args = ["node", str(parser_path)]
      2 print(os.getcwd())
----> 3 p = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
      4 stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
      5 print(stdout)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    705                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    706                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 707                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    708         except:
    709             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
    988                                          env,
    989                                          cwd,
--> 990                                          startupinfo)
    991             finally:
    992                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those 
    pipe

    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: A python error (and not a node error) indicates that Python can't find node (and not that node can't find the argument you specify).  Is it in your PATH?  Should it be node.exe?

Comment: I've checked my PATH variable and nodejs is in there. @jedwards

Comment: Are you able to run the executabley by typing "node" in the *cmd* window? Also try `print(os.environ["PATH"])` before `Popen` to see how things are in the *Python* process environment.

Comment: I've solved this. I made a silly mistake not including shell = True.Thanks for the help btw. @CristiFati

Comment: And yes as I said nodejs was in my path so I was perfectly able to run node in cmd. @CristiFati

Comment: @KranthiKiran I am having the same issue, where exactly did you add the shell = True?

Comment: @YunTaeHwang Here : Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)